# Why is the method CertificateFactory.generateCertifictae(InputStream) getting stuck on an infinite loop?

Tags: java, certificate, runtime-error, x509

i'm receiving a certificate from a server through a socket. For some reason when i execute this instructions:

```
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(socket.getInputStream());
```

The thread gets hanged at an infinite loop of sorts.

Any insight on why this might happen would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The server isn't closing the connection after sending the certificate. You shouldn't acquire certificates via online processes: this is a security risk. You need a secure offline process.

Comment: Sadly i'm kind of tied to this implementation, and further communication needs to happen through this socket, any idea on how to force the reception of the certificate?